# need to publish to server to reflect javascript changes

Tags: javascript, eclipse, git

I am working on a dynamic web project in `eclipse`. Until yesterday, we were using `CVS` for our `version control` system. When I made any change on a `javascript` file, I would just save the file and refresh the browser and the change would be there.

However, since I started using `Git`, I need to publish to the weblogic server in order to see the changes in my browser.

I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: I did nto understand your problem, could you give us more details?

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: post the solution here pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.

I changed a setting in eclipse publishing mode from:

```
Publish as an exploded archive
```

to

```
Publish as a virtual application
```

It isn't related in anyway to `Git` vs `CVS`, it's just that I downloaded a new `eclipse` and the default setting was different from what I previously had.